# React native Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

i have the html part.

```
<CompanyFlatList
              data={companyList}
              keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
              renderItem={({ item }) => (
                <CompanyCardComponent
                  companyName={item.name}
                  goToHomeScreen={() => GoToLoadingScreen(item.code)}
                  randomColor={generateRandomCornerColor()}
                />
              )}
            />
```

i am getting warning message.

```
Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.
```

How to use key props in this?

Comment: I guess that you forgot to use the key on every item on the companyList? Can you show how it is done ?

Comment: Without seeing the code for those components, it's only possible to speculate, but it seems that adding `key={item.id}` prop to `<CompanyCardComponent>` might resolve this.

Comment: no..i am getting same warning after use key={item.id}.

Comment: So maybe it comes from the companyList, as I said before? Can we see it ?
You could maybe provide a reproducible example

Comment: this is the companyList:---
Array [
  Object {
    "code": 465,
    "name": "מעיין",
  },
  Object {
    "code": 485,
    "name": "מעיין",
  },
  Object {
    "code": 984,
    "name": "מפעל הספורט להדגמה",
  },
]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the item.code as a your key

It doesn't need to be `id` necessarily. `item` in keyExtractor will be each member of your array `companyList`, so `item` in your case is an object that looks something like this `{ "code": 465, "name": "מע", }`

```js
<CompanyFlatList
  data={companyList}
  keyExtractor={(item) => item.code} // <----- change this
  renderItem={({ item }) => (
    <CompanyCardComponent
      companyName={item.name}
      goToHomeScreen={() => GoToLoadingScreen(item.code)}
      randomColor={generateRandomCornerColor()}
    />
  )}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a `key` property in every item in your `companyList`, so you should do something like this (this is just an example, I don't know how you are getting your companyList):

```
companyList.forEach(companyItem => companyItem.key = companyItem.code)
```

This way, every item in your list as a uniq key (assuming that the codes are unique)

Comment: i am getting companyList from API.